# Config "development" environment for developer

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm developing an open source application (OrangeHRM) using Symfony framework. How can I change the environment of the project from production to development?

Answer (score 2):

Just make a copy of index.php with frontend_dev.php name and change the configuration line like this:

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);
```

After that just access your project with `http://domain.com/frontend_dev.php`